# Why is my clipboard listener being called twice/application opened twice?

Tags: c#, windows, listener, clipboard, monitor

I Wrote a short program in C# that monitors the clipboard. When a certain string enters the clipboard, a program must be opened with Process.Start (depending on the string). Everything works fine, but sometimes the application is being opened twice. I Don't know why this is happening.

```
namespace ClipboardMonitor {
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        protected static extern int SetClipboardViewer(int hWndNewViewer);
        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove, IntPtr hWndNewNext);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const int SW_SHOW = 5;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        IntPtr nextClipboardViewer;
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            nextClipboardViewer = (IntPtr)SetClipboardViewer((int) this.Handle);
            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
        }
        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing ) {
            ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, nextClipboardViewer);
            if( disposing ) {
                if (components != null) {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.Name = "Form1";
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()  {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) {
            const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
            const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

            switch(m.Msg) {
                case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                    DisplayClipboardData();
                    SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                    break;
                case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                    if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                        nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
                    else
                        SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void DisplayClipboardData() {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            try {
                IDataObject iData = new DataObject();  
                iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                 if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) {
                    string path = iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
                    string[] words = path.Split('_');
                    if (words[0] == "startLO") {
                            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(words[1]);
                            Process p = Process.Start(info);
                    }
                } else {
                    // We doen niets.
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One explanation would be that there are multiple clipboard events happening in rapid succession. This is fairly common.  You can defend against this with a "settle time" delay.  i.e. instead of reacting right away, set a timer or create a thread to handle it "in a little while". As more events come in, keep deferring the settletime.  when the settletime finally expires, the timer or thread is allowed to actually run your program.

Comment: Another explanation is that this code runs in response to *any* change in the clipboard, even if the change has no effect on the text. E.g. somebody adding both text and a bitmap to the clipboard can trigger the `DisplayClipboardData` function twice, once for adding text, and again for adding the bitmap.

Comment: It's happening when I put a simple text on my clipboard (Control + c). Sometimes the application opens 1 time, sometimes it opens 2 times. I've tried to play with a 'settle time' as you can see by the Thread.Sleap(500), but I don't know exactely where I should put this.

Comment: @RaymondChen, an operation involving multiple formats should not cause multiple clipboard notifications unless coded incorrectly. If surrounded by a single set of open/close (clipboard), then there will be only one event sent.  But yes, I HAVE seen this behavior before, long ago.  There was a time when copying an Excel chart would result in 24 clipboard events, one for each format. But they fixed that more than 15 years ago.

Comment: @Jente, your sleep() is not doing anything.  If you get two events, you'll still be running DisplayClipboardData twice, just half a second later. It's like standing at the edge of a canyon and hitting a drum with two quick beats.  500ms later, you hear both of them echo back to you. So what you want to do, is hit the drum twice, but only hear one report, 500ms after the LAST drum beat.

Comment: @ChrisThornton Thank you Chris, I get it. But I haven't got a clue how to do this? Can you provide me with a quick code snippet if possible?